# How to bring an Input dialog box in Android if there is no value in a given file

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, readfile

I need to read a file form Internal storage and if that file doesn't exist or no data in file it should bring an Input dialog box asking the user input.

I tried the below code, but its crashing for some reason.

```
    String textFromFileString = readFromFile();
    if (textFromFileString == "") {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
        alert.setTitle("Alert"); 
        alert.setMessage("Enter Name");

        final EditText input = new EditText(getBaseContext());
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String srt = input.getEditableText().toString();
                    writeToFile(srt);

                } 
        }); 
        alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }); 
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.show();}
```

Comment: Add the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `height` and `width` parameters of your `EditText`:

```
...
final EditText input = new EditText(getBaseContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
input.setLayoutParams(lp);
alert.setView(input);
...
```

Comment: i guess its because of some logic issue, rather than the height-width issue. can you please check the code.

Comment: add your exception log

Comment: did you try my code? also don't use `getBaseContext`, use `YourActivity.this` instead.